# Insert Multiple records in AWS keyspace using C#

Tags: c#, cassandra

Hello I just newly started with Cassandra not much familiar, can u please let me know the error here

I am trying to insert 16000 records using the bellow code

```
public async Task AddSprintsStories(List<SprintStories> sprintStories)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    try
    {
        if (sprintStories.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in sprintStories)
            {
                SprintStories sprintStoryData = new SprintStories();
                sprintStoryData.Id = item.Id;
                sprintStoryData.ProjectId = item.ProjectId;
                sprintStoryData.SprintId = item.SprintId;
                tasks.Add(mapper.InsertAsync<SprintStories>(sprintStoryData, new CqlQueryOptions().SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LocalQuorum)));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

but facing the error: c# Server timeout during write query at consistency LOCALQUORUM (0 peer(s) acknowledged the write over 2 required)

can anyone please help me out here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does the Cassandra cluster look during this cluster?  CPU or disk I/O maxed-out?  Without knowing that, my *guess* is that those 16000 writes are happening faster than your cluster can process them, creating write back pressure.  Finally, it just can't process anymore, so they start failing.

For a possible solution, try limiting the number of active threads.  Something like this should do it.

```
        int maxActiveThreads = 20;    
        int activeThreads = 0;
        foreach (var item in sprintStories)
        {
            ...
            tasks.Add(mapper.InsertAsync<SprintStories>(sprintStoryData, new CqlQueryOptions().SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LocalQuorum)));
            activeThreads++;

            if (activeThreads >= maxActiveThreads)
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                activeThreads = 0;
            }
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

With this code, only 20 writes will be competing for Cassandra cluster resources at any given time.  Do note, that I'm just using 20 as an example.  Adjust that number to something that meets your requirements for performance and stability.

Ryan Svihla wrote a great blog post on this topic- [Cassandra: Batch Loading Without the BATCH - The Nuanced Edition](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-the-nuanced-edition-dd78d61e9885)

Comment: Perfect, Thankx Aaron it worked. The time to insert too is much less..